# Qt + ARToolKit + OpenSceneGraph for mobile development?

Tags: android, qt, augmented-reality, openscenegraph, artoolkit

I want to create an augmented reality app for iOS and Android. 
I'm currently looking for the best strategy to use. 
I want to program in **C++** using **Qt** (for cross-platform) and use **ARToolKit** with **OpenSceneGraph**. Do you know if it is possible? If yes, do I have to build the libraries etc. in a specific way? And will it be better to use cmake or qmake (or something else) in that case ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

My advice for multiplatform development with ARToolKit is to use the Unity plugin. AFAIK there is no integration with QT.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I know there is a possibility to use Artoolkit with OSG but I don't know if it is possible to use that with QT in C++. I want to avoid using Unity which is really closed.. Ideally, I want to develop something usable by another app, like a sdk or something.

Comment: You'll need to link the camera frames from QT towards ARToolkit and provide all the compiled libraries for Android and iOS.

I've looked at it before, actually including QML. It is not trivial.